# How do i keep the CSS styling from affecting other parts of my website?

Tags: html, css, styling

I Am new to code and I am slowly learning using W3schools but I still need help and don't exactly understand certain things.

```
<html>
<body style="background-color:#D2563C;">
<a href="">
<img src="C:\Users\Burke\Desktop\hillbilly 
 \Pictures\bert.png" alt="HTML tutorial" 
 style="width:725px;height:90px;">
</a>
 <style>

a:link, a:visited #tabs{
    box-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: #057A8C;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 31px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type:none
}


a:hover, a:active #tabs{
     background-color: white;
     color: #057A8C
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="center">
<a href="\Desktop\bob\cool.html" 
 target="_blank">Home</a>
<a href="\Desktop\bob\Contact Us.html" 
target="_blank">Contact Us</a>
<a href="Desktop\bob\Printing.html" target="_blank">Printing</a>
<a href="Desktop\bob\Technology.html" 
target="_blank">Technology</a>
<a href="Desktop\bob\Printership.html" 
target="_blank">Printership</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://platform.linkedin.com/badges/js/profile.js" async defer>
</script>


<div class="LI-profile-badge"  data-version="v1" data-size="medium" data-
locale="en_US" data-type="vertical" data-theme="dark" data-
vanity="sullivanstrong"><a class="LI-simple-link" 
href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/sullivanstrong?trk=profile-
badge'>James T kirk</a></div>





</body>
</html>
```

That's my Code

[How do I get the blue border off of the title picture but keep it on the tabs? Also, How do i center the Title Picture and Tabs?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mabrt.png)

Click How do i, to view image,

Comment: Your code seems to be completely unstructured.

Comment: It got messed up during the process of moving it on to the post. @spirit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying your styling to the elements themselves - meaning the styling will always be applied.

There are a few ways to get around this, but the best way would be to use a "class".

Classes can be added to any element. The syntax is:

```
<a href="/example" class="example-class test">Example Link</a>
```

"Class" is added to an element as an "attribute". Classes are split up using spaces. The example above would have 2 separate classes. "example-class" and "test".

You can then apply styling directly to an element using a class. Classes are preceded with a "." (ID's are proceded with a #

```css
.example-class {
  /* styling here */
}
```

Any styling added as above will only be applied to that class. The reason you're getting a blue border on the banner as well is because you are applying your styling to the element directly, so all "a" elements will have the styling attached.

Just to add to this - there are some fundamental issues with the code you have posted. I would advise reading up some basics of HTML and CSS and looking at structure and formatting. Codeacademy is a great place to start:
https://www.codecademy.com/ar/tracks/htmlcss

Example:

```
<a href="\Desktop\bob\jamespak.html" class="tab-class"
 target="_blank">Home</a>

.tab-class {
   /*styling*/
}
```

Comment: so what do I put for the .example-class? Would I do something like .tabs-class {?

Comment: You could add a class to the parent div called "tabs-class", or add it to each tab individually. I've updated the answer with an example

Comment: In my code, where would i need to put the class at? I am sorry I am not exactly understanding what you mean.

Comment: Where would i add the class in the CSS?

Comment: Check answer for updated example. On my phone atm so hard to edit.

Comment: Thank you very much, you were very helpful! That finally fixed the problem! I hope I didn't annoy you too much.

Answer (score 0):

check it out. The snippet is not showing properly. But try it outside. It is working.

https://ibb.co/cG74im

```css
a:link,
a:visited #tabs {
  box-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: #057A8C;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 31px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none
}

a.title {
  border: none;
  display:block !important;
  text-align:center;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  }


a:hover,
a:active #tabs {
  background-color: white;
  color: #057A8C
}
```

```html
<html>
<body style="background-color:#D2563C;">
<a class='title' href="">
<img src="C:\Users\SullivanStrong\Desktop\Hazion 
 Tech\Pictures\HazionTechbanner.png" alt="HTML tutorial" 
 style="width:725px;height:90px;">
</a>
<div class="center">
<a href="sullivanstrong\Desktop\Hazion Tech\Hazion Tech.html" 
 target="_blank">Home</a>
<a href="sullivanstrong\Desktop\Hazion Tech\Contact Us.html" 
target="_blank">Contact Us</a>
<a href="Desktop\Hazion Tech\Printing.html" target="_blank">Printing</a>
<a href="Desktop\Hazion Tech\Technology.html" 
target="_blank">Technology</a>
<a href="Desktop\Hazion Tech\Printership.html" 
target="_blank">Printership</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://platform.linkedin.com/badges/js/profile.js" async defer>
</script>


<div class="LI-profile-badge"  data-version="v1" data-size="medium" data-
locale="en_US" data-type="vertical" data-theme="dark" data-
vanity="sullivanstrong"><a class="LI-simple-link" 
href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/sullivanstrong?trk=profile-
badge'>Sullivan Strong</a></div>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, This really helped the alignment issue!